# How to respond WSO2 ESB proxy after sending an email?

Tags: proxy, wso2, esb, wso2-esb

I'm having troubles with my proxy response after sending an email.

The proxy responds with a blank payload.

I'm using WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus 4.9.0.

This is the part of my proxy that sends email and respond the proxy with an error message:

```
<payloadFactory media-type="xml">
    <format key="ErrorEmailTemplate"/>
</payloadFactory>
<property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="text/html"/>
<property name="ContentType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="text/html"/>
<property name="OUT_ONLY" scope="default" type="STRING" value="true"/>
<property name="FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="true"/>    
<header expression="fn:concat('mailto:', get-property('ErrorEmailAddress'))" name="To" scope="default"/>
<call/>

<payloadFactory media-type="xml">
        <format>
          <updateEmployeesResponse>
            <status>ERROR</status>
          </updateEmployeesResponse>
        </format>
        <args/>
</payloadFactory>
<respond description="Respond to Client"/>
```

I don't know what's the problem, maybe with Header change while sending email.

Comment: Does get-property('ErrorEmailAddress') get relevant value (Ex: correct email address) ? You can add log mediator and test for that.

Comment: The e-mail is working correctly! If I add a log mediator after the second payload factory, I can see that both payload factory is working. The problem is with Respond Mediator.

Comment: Can you add the error message ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED is used to send back a blank response at the end of the mediation with http status code 202.

If you want to send back your own response, remove this property